# How to get Version file to Github Actions

Tags: .net, github-actions

I have a problem with Github Action and version package.
I want to automate the delivery of the nuget package. Here is my yml file.

```yaml
name: Build-pack-publishToNuget

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore ./src/RichLoggerProject/RichLogger/RichLogger.csproj
    - name: Creation du Nugget package
      run: dotnet pack ./src/RichLoggerProject/RichLogger/RichLogger.csproj --configuration Release -o NuGetPackages
    - name: Deploy NuGet Package
      run: dotnet nuget push ./NuGetPackages/RichLogger.1.0.0.nupkg --api-key ${{ secrets.KEYNUGET }} -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

It's done, but I give the full name of file :

```yaml
run: dotnet nuget push ./NuGetPackages/RichLogger.1.0.0.nupkg --api-key ${{ secrets.KEYNUGET }} -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

If I update the version to "1.1.0", I need to change the yml file for :

```yaml
run: dotnet nuget push ./NuGetPackages/RichLogger.1.1.0.nupkg --api-key ${{ secrets.KEYNUGET }} -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

It's not automated  there !
I tried :

```yaml
run: dotnet nuget push ./NuGetPackages/*.nupkg --api-key ${{ secrets.KEYNUGET }} -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

```yaml
run: dotnet nuget push ./NuGetPackages/RichLogger.*.nupkg --api-key ${{ secrets.KEYNUGET }} -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

But I have the same error :
`error: File does not exist (./NuGetPackages/*.nupkg).`
or `error: File does not exist (./NuGetPackages/RichLogger.*.nupkg).`

How I can pass the new version to the command  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution !

When I created the package, the output is `-o NugetPackages` with this line :

```
 - name: Creation du Nugget package
      run: dotnet pack ./src/RichLoggerProject/RichLogger/RichLogger.csproj --configuration Release -o NuGetPackages
```

but when i tried to push the package

```
run: dotnet nuget push ./NuGetPackages/*.nupkg --api-key ${{ secrets.KEYNUGET }} -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

file does not exist.

After many tests, I change to :

```
 - name: Creation du Nugget package
      run: dotnet pack ./src/RichLoggerProject/RichLogger/RichLogger.csproj --configuration Release -o .
```

the output is "**.**", and now the command to push is :

```
- name: Deploy NuGet Package
      run: dotnet nuget push *.nupkg --api-key ${{ secrets.KEYNUGET }} -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --skip-duplicate
```

is done !